# What did Kant mean by "pure physics"?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, kant, philosophy-of-physics, transcendental-idealism, apriorticity-and-aposteriority

Early in the Prolegomena, Kant says that both pure mathematics and pure physics are examples of a priori cognition.  What exactly did he mean by "pure physics"?

Comment: What we today call [Mathematical physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_physics).

Comment: Pure physic consists of propositions which, as Kant puts it, "*are commonly treated at the commencement of proper (empirical) physical science*". By analogy with mathematics, those come from "pure intuition", synthetic activity of understanding and productive imagination without any empirical input. Since those faculties also process empirical sensations what they produce on their own is supposed to apply universally to all of physics. What Kant identifies as such is a vague version of Newtonian mechanics, including the conservation of matter, the action-reaction law and the law of causality.

Comment: Superb! Kant was, as some have pressed upon me, a  genius of the highest order. These men ... and women ... are what we've truly lost, oui mes amies? 

Comment: But the propositions provided by today's mathematical physicists are theoretical and contingent and must be empirically verified.  In that sense, they are not a priori propositions.  Kant implies that such mathematical conclusions do not need confirmation, that the experimental physicist MUST RELY on the math theory, not confirm it.

Answer (score 3):

The clue is in the fact that he called it *a priori*. Pure physics is physics that can be done *a priori* without relying on experimentation. Here is an example from one of Kant's other works.

> All matter is subject to both attracting and repelling forces. If there were no attracting forces between the particles of an object, the object could not hold together. Any disturbance would send the particle all flying off independently. If there were no repelling forces, then the attracting forces would cause all of the particles to converge to a point. Therefore, order for a solid object to exist, the particles of the object must both attract and repel each other.

Note that there is no experimentation here, it's all *a priori* reasoning.

Comment: According to Kant intuition is *a priori*. I'm not sure what you mean by "Hume's theory". Hume claims that our expectation that patterns we have seen in the past will be repeated in the future is wholly unjustified. Kant does not agree with that.

Comment: This is a good start but I'd say some clarity is at hand. Maybe I'll have a bit of time later on.

Comment: And... is he not erring right there already by assuming that "all matter is subject to both attracting and repelling forces" _a priori_? For example, there is no repulsion in the force of gravity. It seems very vague and maybe related to some idea of cosmic balance, but Nature may not comply...

Comment: @Frank, it's *a priori*. That means that unless there is an error in the reasoning, you can know it's true without experimenting. Your gravity counter-example isn't a count-example. The claim isn't that every identifiable force both attracts and repels; the claim is that there is an attracting force and a repelling force.

Comment: Thank you David.  Kant is infamous for being short on examples, this helps a lot.  Now would the a priori assertion that there exist repellant and attractive forces be "analytic" or "synthetic"?  I ask because there seem to be at least two ways in which Kant uses the term "analytic:  1) in the sense of being true by definition and 2) in the sense of inference or implication.  For example, the  existence of solid objects in experience implies attractive forces, and separation of said objects in space implies existence of the opposite force.

Comment: @Gerry, that would be synthetic reasoning. The definition of a physical body does not contain references to internal forces. Those are conclusions drawn from reasoning about the body.

Comment: Let me try asking a different way.  Kant says that the Prolegomena is an "analytic" work and the Critique of Pure Reason is a "synthetic".  I'm not sure what Kant means by that other than perhaps the former is sussing out implied conditions based on given experience and the latter is moving in the opposite direction, starting with first principles and then constructing or deriving experience.

Answer (score 2):

> Now we are nevertheless actually in possession of a pure natural
> science, which, *a priori* and with all of the necessity required for
> apodictic propositions, propounds laws to which nature is
> subject. Here I need call to witness only that propaedeutic to the
> theory of nature which, under the title of universal natural science,
> precedes all of physics (which is founded on empirical principles).
> Therein we find mathematics applied to appearances, and also merely
> discursive principles (from concepts), which make up the philosophical
> part of pure cognition of nature.
> (Kant, Prolegomena, §15)

In other words: Pure natural science is the canon of conditions under which the study of nature (as lawful unity) is possible mathematically.

Comment: +1 I think this bolsters exactly the comments of Mauro above.

Answer (score 0):

You're sure to get a better response from Klocking than this, but one should preface any response by saying that Kant's views are open to interpretation. According to the [SEP article on Transcendental Idealism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-transcendental-idealism/):

> In the Critique of Pure Reason **Kant argues that space and time are merely formal features of how we perceive objects, not things in themselves that exist independently of us, or properties or relations among them**. Objects in space and time are said to be “appearances”, and he argues that we know nothing of substance about the things in themselves of which they are appearances. Kant calls this doctrine (or set of doctrines) “transcendental idealism”, and ever since the publication of the first edition of the Critique of Pure Reason in 1781, Kant’s readers have wondered, and debated, what exactly transcendental idealism is, and have developed quite different interpretations. (my emphasis)

It appears you are quoting:

> One need only attend to the various propositions that appear at the beginning of proper (empirical) physics, such as those of the permanence of the same quantity of matter, of inertia, of the equality of action and reaction, and so on, in order to be soon convinced that **they constitute a pure (or rational) physics, which well deserves, as a science of its own**, to be isolated and established in its entire extent, be it narrow or wide. (my emphasis)

According the [SEP article on Kant and Hume](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-hume-causality/#KantAnswHume):

> [Kant believed] **empirical laws owe their status as “necessary and universally valid” to their relationship with the a priori “pure or universal” laws** (principles) of the understanding. (my emphasis)

According to this [article on Kant and Science](https://cla.umn.edu/philosophy/story/kant-chemistry-and-inexact-sciences), one interpretation of Kant's views on the sciences, and in particular physics is:

> At the top of the hierarchy is physics, which is both proper and rational. Physics, McNulty explains, is rational for Kant because it has laws, and proper because these laws are necessary and can be derived independently of experience. Kant holds that the laws of motion, for example, are derivable from the essential, conceptual nature of matter. **We do not, then, infer through observation that matter is subject to Newton’s laws of motion so much as come to realize that matter must be subject to such laws in order to be observed** at all. (my emphasis)

**Thus, pure physics is the physics that serves as a metaphysical basis for empirical observation.** According to WP's article on Kant's use of the term a priori:

> **Space, time and causality are considered pure a priori intuitions**. Kant reasoned that the pure a priori intuitions are established via his transcendental aesthetic and transcendental logic. He claimed that the human subject would not have the kind of experience that it has were these a priori forms not in some way constitutive of him as a human subject. (my emphasis)

**Thus, the intuitions of physics, the 'pure physics', particularly the physics of Newton which are known through logic and mathematics**, come prior to empirical experience as Hume advocated, and we come to know the universal laws of physics through the [*a priori* (as reformulated by Kant)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori#Immanuel_Kant) intuitions about physics that are perceived by the mind.

Comment: So JD, are you saying that an example of an a priori, or "pure," statement of physics would be Newton's law that an object at rest is still or moving at a constant velocity?

Comment: Okay, with the caveat that I'm not a Kant scholar, and even his English translations are dense reading for me (i.e., I profess no authority whatsoever), my interpretation is that pure physics is the a priori intuitions that arise from the basics of experience of the forms of times and space that can be made as modal statements, and so, wherein Newton can express a Law of Nature, according to Kant, he is expressing pure physics as [conditions of possibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori#Immanuel_Kant).

Comment: So, on my reading, Netwon's laws are not a paradigm of pure physics, but the CULMINATION of pure physics which is more about the intuition that give way to logic. My belief is that pure physics once equations and measurements begin to be bandied about transitions into a special logic that appeals to physics-specific principles.

Comment: But beyond that, I'm ill-equipped to argue the point, sorry.

Comment: It seems to me that pure physics, and pure mathematics, for that matter, are for Kant a priori sciences, and science for Kant is a way of learning or gaining new knowledge through the consistent application of fundamental principles.  That new knowledge could then be expressed in the form of an a priori statement.  For example, given concepts of magnitude and given spatiotemporal intuition, one can learn to add.  The new knowledge so learned can be expressed propositionally, e.g., 7 + 5 = 12.

Comment: Philosophers debate whether or not this is truly analytic but at least tend to agree it is a priori.  So I guess I'm looking for a similar a priori assertion that stems from pure physics.  The best I'm able to discern is that Kant thinks one can imagine objects in the abstract and determine necessary properties that are distinct from mathematical.  If such properties, expressed as a statement, are modal principles , i.e, if they bound experience, they may not actually have to be encountered in experience in the sense that the universe of the possible is bigger than that of the actual

Comment: @Gerry I've been reflecting, and when you say "pure physics, and pure mathematics... are for Kant a priori sciences" I would respond there's a distinction between metaphysics and the sciences in that metaphysics is largely linguistic and intuitive, whereas the sciences are for Kant [exact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_science) because they are logical and objective. Thus, pure physics, as Allegranza has pointed out, is essentially what we know as mathematical physics today, free from the untidy practicalities of physical experimentation which is impure, contaminated by imprecision

Comment: To be clear, I'M not saying "pure physics" and "pure mathematics are a priori sciences."  Kant is.  Prolegomena Section 4:  "But it happens, fortunately, that though we cannot assume metaphysics to be an actual science, we can say with confidence that certain pure a priori synthetic cognitions are actual and given, namely, pure mathematics and pure physics; for both contain propositions which are everywhere recognized as apodeictically certain, partly by mere reason, partly by universal agreement from experience, and yet as independent of experience."

Comment: @Gerry Oh. That makes sense given his views on logic. "Logic is a Rational Science, both as to its form, and also its matter; an *a priori* science of the necessary laws of thought, not, however, in respect to any particular objects, but to all objects generally" - Introduction to Logic. So, yes "Kant thinks one can imagine objects in the abstract and determine necessary properties that are distinct from mathematical." He says so in this passage. Pure physics then is part of the exact science of physics precisely because it is the *a priori* intuition of logic that deals in possible worlds

Comment: S'okay.  My fault.  I should have included the quote in the first place instead of the paraphrase.  What you say makes sense, it's just difficult for me to grok given the science age in which we live.  I can't help but think about Parmenides in the Socratic dialogue who essentially does attempt something like pure physics, not necessarily with good results.

Comment: These are just random qutations and the last one is pure nonsense. Kant doesn't think causality is an 'intuition'.

Comment: @abcga You could be very right in your interpretation of Kant. I'm sure your expertise on Kant is in fact, undeniably true and there is no other room for interpretation. In fact, your answer is far superior to min... wait a second... I think you best post your superior knowledge in a post so that I'm clear that you're not just an Internet troll. Your "nuh-uh" doesn't really seem to be of any assistance.

Comment: @abcga You are going to take the time to give a good answer to show me where my bad answer fails, right?

Comment: So the OP realizes that the subject is complex and open to debate, I merely would post from James R. O'Shea's *Kant's Critique of Pure Reason*, pg. 97: "Kant's transcendental idealist conception of space and time is a hotly disputed aspect of his philosophy... this dispute concerns not only on how to interpret and evaluate the arguments... but also how to understand the transcendental idealist thesis itself." Are you disputing O'Shea's claim? He cites in the same chapter this quotation:

Comment: "We can accordingly speak of space, extended beings, and so on, only from the human standpoint. If we depart from the subjective condition which under alone we can acquire our intuition... then the representation of space signifies nothing at all." Kant CPR, A26-7/B42-3. It could be that my quotes were chosen by dice, and you have the vastly superior understanding, but you'd have to make the effort to back that up. So for my sake and the sake of the OP's knowledge, please, by all means!

Comment: Space, thus, is certainly a subjective intuition, but maybe Kant's emphasis was on the a posteriori nature? Help me to understand.

Comment: @JD Okay, I will provide a better answer. I am just saying that what you wrote is just some random quotes that have nothing to do with the question and are inaccurate (again, causality isn't a form of intuition).

Comment: @abcga Obviously I reject your claim. Causality is indeed a form of intuition, and even Judea's Pearl edifice of mathematical causality doesn't escape it ultimately. I look forward to your answer.

Comment: @JD Where does Kant say that? Causality is a category, a concept, not a formal intuition.

Comment: @abcga Where did I use the term formal intuition? The dichotomy between Kantian categories and formal intuitions are meant to segregate the a priori and the a posteriori, but all experience under a modern conception originates with unsubstantiated beliefs, which is the essence of an [intuition (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuition/). Thus we have both physical intuitions, that align with Kantian formal intuitions, and mental intuitions that align with Kantian categories; neither are products of theoretical reason.

Comment: As I understand it, you seem to be conflating Kant's notion of a formal intuition, with a modern notion of intuition under analytical philosophy more broadly. Again, I encourage you to post an answer to the question. Or not.

Comment: @JD I did post an answer to the question. "Formal intuition" are "form of intuition" are the same for Kant, i.e. he calls space and time either "formal intutions" or "forms of intuition". You can check if you want to. And I'm not sure what are you referring to regarding "mental intuitions". Obviously concepts are not intuitions for Kant. And I don't see that I am conflating anything.

Comment: I mean, there is a distinction between time and space *as* formal intuitions and *as* forms of intuition. It is drawn in a footnote at B160. In either case causality has nothing to do with space and time.

Comment: @abcga Hmmm. I thought it was widely accepted that causality is seen as a distinction class of relationship of spatiotemporal events. But I appreciate the philosophical value of your claims.